# initPayload from SocketClientConfig is not accepting Json-like data

Tags: flutter, websocket, graphql, hasura

### Describe the bug

I'm getting the following error message

```
The argument type 'Map<String, Map<String,String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic> Function()'.
```

for `initPayload` parameter at this code:

```
static final WebSocketLink webSocketLink = WebSocketLink(
    url: 'wss://hasura.io/learn/graphql',
    config: SocketClientConfig(
      autoReconnect: true,
      inactivityTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
      initPayload: {'headers': {'Authorization': _token}},
    ),
  );
```

### To Reproduce

- Following the [GraphQL Flutter Tutorial](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/flutter-graphql/graphql-client/).
- According to [initPayload property](https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql/latest/graphql/SocketClientConfig/initPayload.html) help: `Can be null, but must be a valid json structure if provided.`
- According to [GetInitPayload typedef](https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql/latest/graphql/GetInitPayload.html) help: `typedef GetInitPayload = FutureOr<dynamic> Function();`

Comment: Could that be related to version of node.js? What version you use? Did you tried to change it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer can be found at [this post](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/issues/780#issuecomment-752675928).